# How to decode any string fields in a list that are a byte b'string'

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Migrating code to Python3.6, unpacking and assigning to a list worked in Python2.6 as the whole list was a string, in 3.6 string values are represented as bytecode.  Any value that was an integer is being represented correctly in the list, but any string fields are being represented as bytes still eg: b'B'

Source data is a binary file containing various messages, with various lengths, these messages are successfully being unpacked and stored in a list

Raw byte values data of a sample message

```
b'\x07\x88g\xe0b\xe5]\xc5\x00\x01j\xdd\x00\x01\xff\xdcB\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\n\x00\x00\x03\xe8\x00\x00\x02'
```

```
Unpacked data - using '>I Q I c I Q i H B' on the raw byte values above
[126380000, 7126205086073711325, 131036, b'B', 1, 10, 1000, 0, 2]
```

End state: to implement a generic solution that will detect any b' in a list (can be any index in a list depending on message) convert to a normal string value.

or do not store string values as bytecode during the unpack

```
Current :  [126380000, 7126205086073711325, 131036, b'B', 1, 10, 1000, 0, 2]
End state: [126380000, 7126205086073711325, 131036, B, 1, 10, 1000, 0, 2]
```

Noting b'B' is to be simply represented as B

I have searched google and stackoverflow for a answer, but only find generic decode examples.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no [format character](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#format-characters) for `struct.unpack` that outputs a string, always in bytes.

You can use [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) to decode each `bytes`-type list item to a string.

```
org = [126380000, 7126205086073711325, 131036, b'B', 1, 10, 1000, 0, 2]
res = list(map(lambda i: i.decode("utf-8") if isinstance(i, bytes) else i, org))
```

**EDIT**

As suggested, it can be simpler to use a list comprehension instead of `map`.

```
res = [i.decode("utf-8") if isinstance(i, bytes) else i for i in org]
```

I recommend going through the discussions in [List comprehension vs map](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1247486/2745495) to see when to use one over the other (ex. performance with long/large lists, readability, with/without lambdas, etc.).

Comment: Isn't simpler `res = [i.decode("utf-8") if isinstance(i, bytes) else i for i in org]`?

Comment: @6502 Ahh yes, using list comprehension looks indeed simpler. I've edited it in, and added a link to a related post on list comps vs. maps.

Comment: Excellent!  Thank you very much.  I will profile both versions.  I tried to upvote,  I don't have enough kudos for it to be public :)

Answer (score 0):

**map**

```
        mysetup = "fields = [126380000, 7126205086073711325, 131036, b'B', 1, 10, 1000, 0, 2]"
        mycode = 'fields = list(map(lambda i: i.decode("utf-8") if isinstance(i, bytes) else i, fields))'
        print(timeit.timeit(setup=mysetup, stmt=mycode, number=100000))
```

**Time: 0.24705234917252444**

**List comprehension**

```
        mysetup = "fields = [126380000, 7126205086073711325, 131036, b'B', 1, 10, 1000, 0, 2]"
        mycode = 'fields = [i.decode("utf-8") if isinstance(i, bytes) else i for i in fields]'
        print(timeit.timeit(setup=mysetup, stmt=mycode, number=100000))
```

**Time: 0.1520654000212543**

List comprehension is faster.